Jenkins failed to fetch submodules
I'm facing an issue with my jenkins nightly jobs, where at some nights jenkins failed to fetch submodules properly causing failed jobs. Is there a way to avoid it? I have attached a error logs below.
  * [new branch]          u/matt/mmagic-logging -> origin/u/matt/mmagic-logging
  * [new branch]          u/rob/blynk-port-poc  -> origin/u/rob/blynk-port-poc
  * [new tag]             rel_2_4_6_2024_05_10  -> rel_2_4_6_2024_05_10
 Could not access submodule 'firmware/driver'
 
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2842)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2185)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:635)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler$GitCommandMasterToSlaveCallable.call(RemoteGitImpl.java:170)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler$GitCommandMasterToSlaveCallable.call(RemoteGitImpl.java:161)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:211)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:54)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:377)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService.lambda$wrap$0(InterceptingExecutorService.java:78)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
    Suppressed: hudson.remoting.Channel$CallSiteStackTrace: Remote call to Sanity_builder
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1784)
        at hudson.remoting.UserRequest$ExceptionResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:356)
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:1000)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler.execute(RemoteGitImpl.java:153)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor834.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteGitImpl.java:138)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy212.execute(Unknown Source)
        at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:997)
        at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1241)
        at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1305)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep.checkout(SCMStep.java:129)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:97)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:84)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

I have already made recursive submodules option to false just to avoid this issue in my jenkins  SCM checkout, but still facing this issue.
checkout([
                        $class: 'GitSCM',
                        branches: [[name: "${params.morse_firmware}"]],
                        doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false,
                        extensions: [[$class: 'SubmoduleOption',
                            disableSubmodules: false,
                            parentCredentials: true,
                            recursiveSubmodules: false,
                            reference: '',
                            timeout: 10,
                            trackingSubmodules: false],
                            [$class: 'CleanBeforeCheckout',
                            deleteUntrackedNestedRepositories: true]],
                        submoduleCfg: [],
                        userRemoteConfigs:```

